# cast function argument based on version argument to avoid duplicate code

Tags: c, struct

I have a function as below. It takes 2 arguments. One is a void pointer which points to a struct and other is the version number. Depending on the version passed the void pointer needs to be cast to 2 structure which are almost similar.(One has an array and other uses a pointer).

```
struct some_v0{
    char a;
    int some_array[200];
    char b;
}
struct some_v0{
    char a;
    int *some_array;
    char b;
}
void some_api(void * some_struct, int version){
    /* Depending on version the void pointer is cast to 2 different version of a struct*/
    /* This is followed by some common code which is similar for both version of struct(as array access and pointer access have similar code)*/
}
```

As both array access and pointer access has similar code, the only difference between two version is the casting of void pointer.

My current method is as below.

```
void some_api(void * some_struct, int version){


    if(version == 0){
        struct some_v0 v0;
        v0= *(struct some_v0 *)some_struct;
        /* block of code which uses v0 */
    }
    if(version == 1){
        struct some_v1 v1;
        v1= *(struct some_v1 *)some_struct;
        /* block of code which uses v1 */
    }
}
```

The block of code used above are similar, as array access and pointer access are similar. I want to avoid the duplicate code in the above case. Any help is appreciated. I am looking for a solution which can help me avoid duplicate code.

Note: I cannot change the order in which struct members are defined. I understand that if the array was the last element in struct definition, the solution is easy. I am not allowed to change order of struct element for backward compatibility reasons.

Edit 1: I have one more similar API where I need to fill the input struct and return it to calling function.

```
void some_api(void * some_struct, int version){


    if(version == 0){
        struct some_v0 *v0;
        v0= (struct some_v0 *)some_struct;
        /* block of code which uses v0  fill v0*/
    }
    if(version == 1){
        struct some_v1 *v1;
        v1= (struct some_v1 *)some_struct;
        /* block of code which uses v1. Fill v1 */
    }
}
```

I am looking for a solution that can handle this case too and avoid duplicate code.

Comment: "*block of code used above are similar ....*" *similar* or *equal*? Perhaps you like to show this code in question to us?

Comment: @alk The code block is equal. only difference in my current solution is that one uses v0 and other uses v1.

Comment: do you absolutely have to use C or is C++ possible?

Comment: @Raja Only C cab be used. No C++ :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for your generality problem, you can actually use the `some_v1` structure to access the `some_v0` structure, if the only difference is the array in v0 versus the pointer in v1.

Like

```
struct some_v1 v1;

if(version == 0){
    v1.a = ((struct some_v0 *) some_struct)->a;
    v1.some_array = ((struct some_v0 *) some_struct)->some_array;
    v1.b = ((struct some_v0 *) some_struct)->b;
} else if (version == 1)
    v1 = *(struct some_v1 *) some_struct;
}
```

After this, the structure `v1` can be used for both versions.

---

If you later add a `some_v2` structure which only adds members to the `some_v1` structure, then you can use the same technique. Just remember to set the fields in the v2 structure after copying the v1 structure.

For example

```
struct some_v2
{
    char a;
    int *some_array;
    char b;
    int c;  /* New field in v2 */
};
```

Then you can do

```
struct some_v2 v2;

if(version == 0){
    v2.a = ((struct some_v0 *) some_struct)->a;
    v2.some_array = ((struct some_v0 *) some_struct)->some_array;
    v2.b = ((struct some_v0 *) some_struct)->b;
    v2.c = 0;
} else if (version == 1)
    memcpy(&v2, some_struct, sizeof(struct some_v1));
    v2.c = 0;
} else {
    v2 = *(struct some_v2 *) some_struct;
}
```

I recommend putting all this in a separate function, so it can easily be reused when needed.

---

After the update of the question, if you want to use pointers you could do something like this (considering the original with only two versions of the structure):

```
struct some_v1 v1_np;  /* Non-pointer structure */
struct some_v1 *v1;  /* the pointer we will work with */

if (version == 0) {
    v1_np.a = ((struct some_v0 *) some_struct)->a;
    v1_np.some_array = ((struct some_v0 *) some_struct)->some_array;
    v1_np.b = ((struct some_v0 *) some_struct)->b;
    v1 = &v1_np;
} else if (version == 1) {
    v1 = (struct some_v1 *) some_struct;
}
```

As seen this is very much like the original version. The problem here is that the v0 and v1 structures are not compatible in any way (try checking `sizeof` of both structures and you might understand why), that's why you need a temporary `v1_np` structure that you can make `v1` point to.

Comment: This looks good. What if `struct some_v1 v1;` is a pointer? `struct some_v1 *v1;`. I hope this works for pointer too, right?

Comment: @Ravichandra Unfortunately it won't work very well when using pointers (i.e. making a `some_v1` structure pointer point to `some_data`). The problem is that if you pass in a `some_v0` structure the `b` member will not be at the same offset in the `v0` structure compared to the `v1` structure. Also, if you later add a `v2` structure, then you can't just make a pointer `v2` and make it point to a `v1` structure, as whenever you access e.g. the `c` member of the `v2` structure you will read (or worse, write) outside the allocated memory.

Comment: @Ravichandra There is however a light at the end of the tunnel. If, and I really mean **if**, the `some_struct` is actually *always* the latest version of the structure, then you can simply cast it as a pointer (for versions later than `v0` which still needs special handling). Then simply check the version number before accessing field members.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please update your answer so that I can accept it as answer?

Comment: @Ravichandra Updated answer. It's not that much different from the original anyway, because of the differences between the two structures.

Comment: In the updated answer u did `v1 = &v1_np;` for `version == 0`  where `v1_np` is a local variable. The calling function may not have access to it when this function returns?

Comment: @Ravichandra No, this is why I suggest you put the code to get the structure in a separate function, so you can call it whenever needed. Also, you should probably get the structure as early as possible, and use it for as much code as possible, so you don't have to do hacks like this.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this problem.

Instead of having 2 versions of struct, I introduced a new struct member in some_v0 as below. 
Note: I am not changing the order of struct members here.

```
struct some_v0{
    char a;
    int some_array[200];
    char b;
    int *some_array_v1;
};
```

The API function can be implemented as:

```
void some_api(void * some_struct, int version){
    struct *some_v0 v0= (some_v0 *)ptr;
    int *ptr; /*pointer we will be working on*/
    if (version == 0) {
         ptr=some_v0->some_array;
    } else if (version == 1) {
         ptr=some_v0->some_array_v1;
    }
/*Common code block which uses ptr wherever some_arry is used. All other members can be dereferenced using v0*/
}
```

This avoids duplicate code and also handles api versions. This also take care of returning the values in struct pointer, so that calling function can use it.

Comment: Are you able to rebuild the entire suite?  If you can't rebuild everything that uses some_v0, then you might get an access violation.  Also, watch out for memory leaks when you free a some_v0 structure.  You will need to free some_array_v1 as well unless it is a static constant.

Comment: @cup I am rebuilding entire suite. It consists of a main program which loads a library which has these apis. I need to take care of backward compatibility when new main program tries to load old library. This I think is handled in above code using version. the structures are static structures. Even if the caller allocates the structure, depending on version of api, they have to allocate and free some_array_v1. If they are using older structure then they will not allocate memory for some_array_v1.

Comment: Also when old main program tries to load new library there wont be any allocation for some_array_v1. So I think there wont be access violation or memory leak. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That is not a problem: I've just seen so many pieces of code where a race condition exists when uninitialized pointers are accessed.  It just sets alarm bells ringing whenever I see code like that.  It is sometimes unfounded but I get paranoid and start checking wherever the structure is being accessed.